# Samba login fails

Tags: centos, windows, login, smb

I setup an Samba server and I tried to connect to it from a machine in the same VLAN, I can see the shares, and it asks me for a password but after that it fails with the following 2 lines in the LOG:

[2018/02/19 11:21:07.725300,  5] 
../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:1825(lookup_global_sam_rid)
  **Can't find a unix id for an unmapped group**

[2018/02/19 11:21:07.725317,  5] 
../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:1535(pdb_default_sid_to_id)
  **SID S-1-5-21-3363938291-73671434-3978610123-513 belongs to our domain, but 
there is no corresponding object in the database.**

Does anyone know what this is and why? As on other servers I setup with basically the same [global] section I don't have that issue.

The machine I use is a CentOS 7.4 machine with the standard Samba server. And a Windows 7 SP1 VM to connect to the shares.

I did add the:       "ntlm auth = yes " option. Otherwise we had issues with Windows 10. But is there a simular option required for Windows 7 machines in the combination?

Thanks

Comment: Did you do `smbpasswd -a username` and set a samba password for whatever user you are connecting as?

Comment: Yes I've added 3 users that way, but all 3 cannot connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the directory and file permissions on the share itself.

My share was set to allow `root:users`. But my SMB account (or the local unix account it was mapped to) was not a member of `users`

I could see from the SMB logs that authentication was succeeding:

`check_ntlm_password:  PAM Account for user [<my_user>] succeeded`

so it was something downstream of that.

In my case, the solution was to add the user to the group...

`sudo usermod -a -G users <my_user>`

I suppose you could do this by `chown`ing the directory too.

I restarted SMB for good measure (`sudo service smbd restart`) and connected immediately.